# GDrive Multipart upload jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

I followed the whole steps from google and I got some codes that I found here to make, and so I'm trying to upload a file from a form to Google Drive using the API, and that's the code:

```js
var importFiles = $('#files')[0].files;

const boundary = '--cloud';
const delimiter = "\r\n" + boundary + "\r\n";
const close_delim = "\r\n" + boundary + "--";

var metadata = {
    'name': importFiles[0]["name"],
    'mimeType': importFiles[0]["type"],
    'parents': ['parent-id']
};

var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter +
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) + "\r\n" +
    delimiter + "\r\n" +
    'Content-Type: ' + importFiles[0]["type"] + "\r\n\r\n" +
    importFiles[0] +
    close_delim;

gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
    'method': 'POST',
    'params': {
        'uploadType': 'multipart'
    },
    'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.client.getToken()["access_token"],
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="cloud"'
    },
    'body': multipartRequestBody
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Google receives the information, and creates the file, the problem is that seems the file isn't going to Google or I don't know, all I got it's just the Google File without content. When I try to make a sample upload, everything goes well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your script is almost correct. But it is required to modify a little. So how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points :

- In this modification, the file is converted to the base64 data and used to the request body.
- In order to use the base64 data, it modifies the request body.

  - Added `'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' +`.

#### Modified script :

```
var importFiles = $('#files')[0].files;

const boundary = '--cloud';
const delimiter = "\r\n" + boundary + "\r\n";
const close_delim = "\r\n" + boundary + "--";

var metadata = {
    'name': importFiles[0]["name"],
    'mimeType': importFiles[0]["type"],
    'parents': ['parent-id']
};

var f = new FileReader();  // Added
f.onload = function(){  // Added
  var multipartRequestBody =
      delimiter +
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' +
      JSON.stringify(metadata) +
      delimiter +
      'Content-Type: ' + importFiles[0]["type"] + "\r\n" +
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' +  // Added
      btoa(this.result) +  // Modified
      closeDelim;

  gapi.client.request({
      'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files',
      'method': 'POST',
      'params': {
          'uploadType': 'multipart',
      },
      'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.client.getToken()["access_token"],
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary="cloud"',
      },
      'body': multipartRequestBody,
  }).then(function(r) {  // Added
    console.log(r);  // Added
  });  // Added
};
f.readAsBinaryString(importFiles[0]);  // Added. I think that you can also use readAsDataURL().
```

#### Note :

- This modified script supposes as follows.

  - Your access token can be used for uploading files to Google Drive.
  - From `Google receives the information, and creates the file` in your question, your script has already got ready to be used for uploading files.

Although in my environment, I confirmed that this script worked, if this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: You just saved my life, thank you very much .... Just to know, is this script useful to upload also large files like videos?

Comment: @Leo Letto Welcome. When uploadType is multipart, the maximum size of files is 5 MB. If you want to upload the files with more than 5 MB using Drive API, I recommend to use the resumable upload. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resumable-upload As a simple tip, if you want to upload files with less than 50 MB, you can do it using Web Apps. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web But in this case, the script for uploading is required to be put in Google Drive.

Comment: got it, thank you.... I will try to do the same with a resumable upload

Comment: Welcome. About the resumable upload, is this information useful for you? https://github.com/tanaikech/Resumable_Upload_For_WebApps